# If statment with an array of numbers

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

I have an array of numbers

```
x = np.arange(-5., 5., .001)
```

and an equation that is

```
y=somefunction(x*r)
```

When absolute value of x is less than .1, I want to let r=5, otherwise r=0. Then, I should get len(x) many values of y.

This is what I've *tried*:

```
if abs(x) < .1 : 
    r=5
else:
    r=0
```

Comment: Do you mean: When the absolute value of x  is less than 0.1 ?

Comment: Look into `numpy.vectorize` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: @Kingsley yes. will correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it will work. Instead of using if-else use vectorization method. This method is faster than if-else. My suggestion is that always try to use vectorization methods for the speedy process instead of using if-else,for-loops,etc.

```
x = np.arange(-5., 5., .001)
print(x)
output: array([-5.   , -4.999, -4.998, ...,  4.997,  4.998,  4.999])

x[abs(x)< .1]=5
x[abs(x)> .1]=0
```

Again you can print values of x variable and you will see the change.

Hopefully, this will help you. Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, this worked. However, since I also had to use x in my function, I just had to create a new array for r and then replaced all of the x's for r's here. But yes, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome @Mckenzie. Sorry, I forgot to inform that but you can create another same variable value for r's like x's.

Comment: `r = np.empty_like(x)`